# Flattening Tuples in Haskell (pointfree)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pointfree

I've recently picked up Haskell and I'm trying writing a simple program to sort acronyms. Basically, I have a list of acronyms  - each acronym is a pair of Strings, for example ("DH", "Diffie-Hellman") - and I want to sort them and print them in the following format (Acronym, Meaning, Index).

For example, if

```
acronyms = [("ECDLP", "elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem"),
            ("DH", "Diffie-Hellman"),
            ("KDF", "key derivation function")]
```

then the output should be

```
("DH","Diffie-Hellman",1)
("ECDLP","Elliptic Curve Discrete Logarithm Problem",2)
("KDF","Key Derivation Function",3)
```

Currently, the code I have is the following.

```
main :: IO ()
main =
    mapM_
        print
        (zipWith
             (curry (\((a, b), c) -> (a, b, c)))
             (sort . nub $ map (capitalise <$>) acronyms)
             [1 ..])
```

Here capitalise is a function that I wrote that capitalises the first character of each word in a string. Overall, this program is working but I would like to get some feedback on how I can improve it. Finally, is there any way I could make this `curry (\((a, b), c) -> (a, b, c))` part in the pointfree style?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need `curry` for this, you can instead use `zipWith (\(a, b) c -> (a, b, c))`. You can consider using [zipWith3](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:zipWith3) but it doesn't make as much sense if the key-value pairs in `acronyms` should stay together.

Comment: What's the point in printing the index in the list **after** sorting, along with each item? You always know it's going to be 1 on the first line, 2 on the 2nd, etc... it adds no information to the data. Are you sure you haven't misread the assignment and it is actually supposed to be the index in the **original** list, before sorting? That would actually make the output more informative (since it also tells you where the item originally was). I might well be wrong, since assignments don't need to have any practical requirements, but might be worth taking another look.

Comment: I want the index after sorting because I'm then writing them to a file acronyms.tex and the index is needed for the acronym to be rendered properly.

Answer (score 4):

## Code Review

First off, the `curry` really is just adding complexity. You can write a lambda that takes multiple arguments without it. Rather than

```
curry (\((a, b), c) -> (a, b, c))
```

consider

```
\(a, b) c -> (a, b, c)
```

Now, you seem to have the idea that everything should be pointfree. That's a neat exercise for recreational programming and can be useful in code golf (where the goal is to shorten the code as much as possible), but when you're writing general-purpose software it's often a poor design choice (where the goal is to make the code as *readable* as possible). So I'd recommend introducing some local variables and some additional functions to take care of the intermediaries.

We can split the zipping part off into a separate function

```
enumerateAcronyms :: [(a, b)] -> [(a, b, Int)]
enumerateAcronyms xs = zipWith (\(a, b) c -> (a, b, c)) xs [1..]
```

Note that, although we *use* this function as `[(String, String)] -> [(String, String, Int)]`, I write it as `[(a, b)] -> [(a, b, Int)]`. This more general type provides very strong guarantees about what we do with our input. Namely, we won't modify the first two elements of the tuple; *all* we will do is move them around and associate integers with them.

The `Functor` instance for `(,) a` is weird. It took me a minute to realize that `(capitalize <$>)` meant "do it to the second element of the tuple". So you should either do so explicitly

```
\(x, y) -> (x, capitalize y)
```

or use a name that more clearly matches your intention. In this case, we actually have two choices: [`Control.Arrow.second`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#v:second) or [`Data.Bifunctor.second`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:second). They do the same thing and are simply based on different abstractions (the former abstracts on the function type and the latter on the data structure).

```
second capitalize
```

My personal preference is to never use the list-specific functions like `map` and to always use the general functor `fmap`. That way, if you want to expand this function to be generic and work over, say, [sequences](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.5.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html) or some other data structure, you have less work to do.

`nub` is O(n^2), which is fine if you're preserving the order of the list. But if you're sorting the list, we can get it in O(n) by rolling it ourselves. So let's write our own `nub`.

Likewise, I might replace [`mapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_), which requires `Monad`, with the identical [`traverse_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:traverse_), which only requires `Applicative` and hence works in more general situations.

Finally, I'm not a huge fan of chaining together long sequences of operations. Some people do it, but I don't like reading my code right-to-left, so rather than

```
main :: IO ()
main = traverse_ print (enumerateAcronyms (uniqSort $ map (second capitalise) acronyms))
```

I would probably write

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  let uniqAcronyms = uniqSort $ map (second capitalise) acronyms
  in traverse_ print (enumerateAcronyms uniqAcronyms)
```

For a grand total of something like

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Data.Bifunctor
import Data.Foldable

acronyms :: [(String, String)]
acronyms = [("ECDLP", "elliptic curve discrete logarithm problem"),
            ("DH", "Diffie-Hellman"),
            ("KDF", "key derivation function")]

capitaliseFirst :: String -> String
capitaliseFirst [] = []
capitaliseFirst (x:xs) = toUpper x : xs

capitalise :: String -> String
capitalise = unwords . fmap capitaliseFirst . words

enumerateAcronyms :: [(a, b)] -> [(a, b, Int)]
enumerateAcronyms xs = zipWith (\(a, b) c -> (a, b, c)) xs [1..]

uniqSort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
uniqSort = go . sort
    where go [] = []
          go [x] = [x]
          go (x:x':xs)
             | x == x' = go (x':xs)
             | otherwise = x : go (x':xs)

main :: IO ()
main =
  let uniqAcronyms = uniqSort $ map (second capitalise) acronyms
  in traverse_ print (enumerateAcronyms uniqAcronyms)
```

This is much longer than what you wrote, but it's also going to be much clearer to the average Haskell programmer. There's a lot less to have to keep in your head when reading any particular function, so the code is much easier to break down. If you're coming from Java or some other languages, you've seen the opposite side of this: Code is far too verbose and split across ten files, which makes it hard to see what's going on. But in Haskell, we run into the opposite issue: Code can get too short and snazzy and it gets hard to reason about. There's a happy medium to be reached in the middle.

## Pointfree

Now, to answer your initial question: Can we pointfree `curry (\((a, b), c) -> (a, b, c))`? I don't recommend doing it in production code, as it's definitely not readable, but let's explore. First, as mentioned, the `curry` isn't necessary. This is just

```
\(a, b) c -> (a, b, c)
```

which is

```
\(a, b) c -> (,,) a b c
```

then it's just a matter of moving variables around and getting rid of the tuple. `c` can be eliminated, hence

```
\(a, b) -> (,,) a b
```

Now we have a 2-tuple on the left and two arguments on the right. The difference between those is `uncurry`, hence

```
\(a, b) -> uncurry (,,) (a, b)
```

and then we eliminate the last element

```
uncurry (,,)
```

but of course, I have no idea what that does at a glance, whereas `\(a, b) c -> (a, b, c)` is pretty self-explanatory.

In general, we can pointfree any Haskell function provided we have [catamorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catamorphism) for any data structures used (this is [`maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe) for `Maybe`, or [`foldr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) for lists), as well as some basic quality-of-life functions in the prelude. You can use other tricks like the reader monad or `liftA2` to make things easier or shorter, but fundamentally you don't need things like that. It's just a matter of being able to move variables around the various Haskell syntax elements. You convert recursion into `fix`, pattern matching into catamorphisms, and arguments that are in the "wrong" order into several [`flip`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:flip) calls.

[Lambdabot](https://wiki.haskell.org/Lambdabot) used to be able to automatically pointfree most Haskell expressions using this systematic approach. I'm not sure if it's still around or not.

Comment: http://pointfree.io/ still exists

Comment: `uniqSort = map head . group . sort`

Answer (score 2):

Parallel list comprehensions completely eliminate the futzing about with tuples (`zipWith`, `curry`, the lambda, and `(<$>)`), which I think makes it much more readable. Also, since you're sorting anyway, you don't need `nub` -- simply `group`ing adjacent equal elements will be enough. So:

```
{-# Language ParallelListComp #-}

main = mapM_ print
    [ (acronym, capitalise meaning, i)
    | (acronym, meaning):_ <- group (sort acronyms)
    | i <- [1..]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by making it less point-free! That `curry` is a mess, and accomplishing nothing. Just write a lambda that combines a tuple with an index directly.

```
main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ print . zipWith output [1 ..] . sort . nub . map (fmap capitalise) $ acronyms
  where output idx (acronym, meaning) = (acronym, meaning, idx)
```

This is fine, but I think the fmap instance for tuples is surprising enough that, in code I wanted anyone else to read, I'd name that function too:

```
main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ print . zipWith output [1 ..] . sort . nub . map capitaliseDefinition $ acronyms
  where output idx (acronym, meaning) = (acronym, meaning, idx)
        capitaliseDefinition (acronym, meaning) = (acronym, capitalise meaning)
```

You could also be more modern, and use `traverse_` instead of `mapM_`. I'm sympathetic to the clingers-on of `mapM_`, though - the name is more obviously indicative of what it does.